# Getting the Error Where Jquery is used in my Application

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

Iam using Jquery for Long time for my  Application .Suddenly today it started giving me error on every page where jquery is used .The error is "syntax error on line 2  and character 1" .It is giving me the same error for all the pages where Jquery is used .The Jquery version we are using is  Jquery v(1.4.2) and the UI Version we are using is (1.8).we are using the same thing in the production it is working fine .It is giving us error in our development Especially IE 6.0 .Rest all the other browsers are working fine .How do i Debug this .Hoe can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade jquery or jquery-ui very recently?

Try creating a totally empty page that only loads jquery and/or runs a single line of code and nothing else, then when you have that working, work back up to the full functionality of your site/application.

Is the error you're getting only in IE6?

Comment: Just only in IE6.0 .it is working fine in IE8.0, Firefox and chrome

Comment: When developing using javascript, I like to add alerts in my code when I have an error I need to track down. If you don't see a certain alert, you know that the point in the code the alert is was never reached. You can sprinkle your jquery file with these (make sure to make a backup just in case) and try to find the exact statement that IE6 is getting worked up about.